# System freezes after standby

Tags: hibernate

I have Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my laptop. (Toshiba Satellite A 210) It has a AMD Turion 64 x2 cpu. 
Whenever I put my system into standby, it freezes after returning from standby. Can anybody help me. This also happened in 10.04 but not in 9.10.

Comment: I have Toshiba Satellite M40X and ubuntu Desktop 12.04LTS. This bug still exists. I don't remember this in previous versions but I could be wrong...

Answer (score 2):

This is a common bug, and a plague of Ubuntu as far as I can understand.

I've been with ubuntu for 2 years now, and this is the first system I've had where I can reliable suspend and restore without any issues.

Your best bet for getting an answer is to search the [ubuntu bug reports at Launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/)

Here is one bug report matching this problem, though from a previous release:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/185254

Comment: Ehm Okay. Now hibernate and stanby are working fine Oo

Comment: No..hm. sometimes it works but sometimes not Oo

Answer (score 1):

I'm also on a Toshiba Sattelite Laptop and my computer goes to suspend mode just fine but when i try to wake it up, hdd and other things wake up but my screen stays black and it looks like the display did not wake up from the suspend.

I think it's just that suspend is not supported on all computers...

Answer (score 1):

I also have a toshiba, I discovered that after suspend, the open monitor icon in the panel shows both cores running at 100%. With such monopolization of the CPU, other processes may run, but very slow.

I opened a terminal (use the -T shortcut if the mouse is not working fine)

and listed the running processes:

```
ps -A
```

I saw that two processes were active: `snort` and `sip2ncid`, 
I killed both, with `kill <pid>`.

One can learn about those programs with the `apropos` command.

But I do not know exactly what are those programs for

HW is a satellite u205 intell core2duo@2GHz, Ubuntu 10.04 x86-64 with gnome.
I do not remember bios ver, now, I also do not remember how to display it now, but is the last one available from toshiba.